# Postgresql - How do I extract the first occurence of a substring in a string using a regular expression pattern?

Tags: regex, string, postgresql

I am trying to extract a substring from a text column using a regular expression, but in some cases, there are multiple instances of that substring in the string.

In those cases, I am finding that the query does not return the first occurrence of the substring. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

For example:

If I have this data:

```
create table data1
(full_text text, name text);

insert into data1 (full_text)
values ('I 56, donkey, moon, I 92')
```

I am using

```
UPDATE data1
SET name = substring(full_text from '%#"I ([0-9]{1,3})#"%' for '#')
```

and I want to get `'I 56'` not `'I 92'`

Comment: Please add the definition of the table (as `create table`) , some sample data  (ideally as `insert` statements) and the expected output based on that data (formatted text please no screen shots)

Comment: [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35371982/edit) your question. Do **not** post code in comments.

Comment: `split_part(yourColumn, 'delimiter', 1)`

Answer (score 15):

You can use `regexp_matches()` instead:

```
update data1
  set full_text = (regexp_matches(full_text, 'I [0-9]{1,3}'))[1];
```

As no additional flag is passed, `regexp_matches()` only returns the first match - but it returns an array so you need to pick the first (and only) element from the result (that's the `[1]` part)

It is probably a good idea to limit the update to only rows that would match the regex in the first place:

```
update data1
  set full_text = (regexp_matches(full_text, 'I [0-9]{1,3}'))[1]
where full_text ~ 'I [0-9]{1,3}'
```

Comment: I find it a little weird the regexp_matches() is implemented so that by default, it will return an array with a single item... they should've added a regexp_match() function

Comment: In my encounter with this issue I was extremely confused about why my array access wasn't working. I find this to be a related question/answer: [Why is it necessary to add parenthesis when accessing an array returned by a fun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39906634/why-is-it-necessary-to-add-parenthesis-when-accessing-an-array-returned-by-a-fun)

Comment: I have a big performance issue looking for a patern in a narrative because regex_match goes through the whole text searching for possible matches. I only need it to get first one that usually is at the beginning of the narrative and exit right away, so it can go through thousand of records more efficiently.

Comment: ... perhaps regexp_substr() in Postgresql version 15 can do the job of getting only the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following expression. It will return the first occurrence:

```
SUBSTRING(full_text, 'I [0-9]{1,3}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `regexp_match()` In PostgreSQL 10+

```
select regexp_match('I 56, donkey, moon, I 92', 'I [0-9]{1,3}');
```

Quote from [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-TABLE):

> In most cases regexp_matches() should be used with the g flag, since
> if you only want the first match, it's easier and more efficient to
> use regexp_match(). However, regexp_match() only exists in PostgreSQL
> version 10 and up. When working in older versions, a common trick is
> to place a regexp_matches() call in a sub-select...