# why is it necessary to add parenthesis when accessing an array returned by a function (in SELECT)?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

Coming from (script) programming languages, I do not understand why this **does not** work

```
SELECT regexp_matches('hello world', '(he).*(wo)', 'g')[1];
```

while adding additional parenthesis **does** work (at least in Postgres).

```
SELECT (regexp_matches('hello world', '(he).*(wo)', 'g'))[1];
```

I would have assumed that the array returned by `regexp_matches` is accessed in both cases, but I guess my syntax understanding of SQL is lacking here.

**So why do we need the parenthesis?**

Comment: I'm probably being anal - but you didn't add brackets, you added parentheses - [] are brackets (like [1] is in brackets)

Comment: @mageeworld uups. In German, brackets and parenthesis is the same word. Thanks. corrected it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the brackets have a pretty high [precedence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE-TABLE) , so your query is parsed as

```
SELECT regexp_matches(('hello world', '(he).*(wo)', 'g')[1]);
```

This doesn't make sense, you want to apply the index on the result of calling `regexp_matches()` , so you have to add parenthesis to group the regexp_matches call.

(Note these two characters  [] are brackets, you added parenthesis, not brackets